# How to find the value of $\sin(\frac\pi7)\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7})\sin(\frac{3\pi}{7})\;$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am quite stuck with this problem.
The problem is to find the value of

$$P = \sin\left(\!\frac\pi7\!\right)\sin\left(\!\frac{2\pi}{7}\!\right)\sin\left(\!\frac{3\pi}{7}\!\right)$$

I tried doing it by turning sines into cosines and then applying the cosine sum series formula , but there were too many unknown angles that were not manipulatable , so I did my working on only sines , though I still ended no where.

So what should be done here?

Comment: **Hint**: $\sin \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma = \frac{1}{4}\left[ \sin(\alpha+\beta-\gamma)+\sin(\beta+\gamma-\alpha)+\sin(\gamma+\alpha-\beta)-\sin(\alpha+\beta+\gamma) \right]$

Comment: I actually ended up proving the expression well same thing happened full of unknown angles and not much of formulas I could use after solving the expression

Comment: In general one may ask the question what means the term "evaluation" especially if the result is not a rational number. Probably a better term here were "simplification", though it is also ambiguous.

Comment: $$\prod_{r=1}^{n-1} \ sin\left(\frac{r\pi}{n}\right)=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

One can prove that $$\frac{\sin(\pi/7)}{\sqrt 7},-\frac{\sin(2\pi/7)}{\sqrt 7},\quad \text{and}\quad -\frac{\sin(3\pi/7)}{\sqrt 7},$$
are the roots of $$p(x)=x^3+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{56}.$$
I let you continue.

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

There is a very useful property of the product of sines:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{\pi k}n=n.\tag1
$$

This should be enough to solve the problem.

> The property $(1)$ can be easily proved evaluating the identity $$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(z-e^{i\frac{2\pi k}n}\right)=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^k$$ at $z=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Square $P$ then you can use some identities, in particular Identity 3 below.

$P=\sin (\pi /7)\sin(2\pi/7)\sin(3\pi/7)$

$P^2=\frac{1}{8}(1-\cos 2\pi/7)(1-\cos4\pi/7)(1-\cos 6\pi/7)$

**Identity 1: $\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)=2\cos A\cos B$**

**Identity 2: $\cos (k\pi/7)=\cos \frac{(14-k)\pi}{7}$**

$8P^2=(1-\cos 2\pi/7)(1-\cos 6\pi/7 - \cos 4\pi/7 + \cos 4\pi/7 \cos6\pi/7)$

$16P^2=(1- \cos 2\pi/7)(2-2\cos 6\pi/7 - 2 \cos 4\pi/7+ \cos 2\pi/7 + \cos 4\pi/7 )$

$16P^2=(1- \cos 2\pi/7)(2 -2 \cos 6\pi/7 +\cos 2\pi/7 - \cos 4\pi/7)$

$16P^2=2 -2 \cos 6\pi/7 +\cos 2\pi/7 - \cos 4\pi/7 - 2 \cos (2\pi /7)+ 2 \cos (2\pi/7)\cos(6\pi/7)- \cos^2(2\pi/7)+ \cos (2\pi/7)\cos (4\pi/7)$

$16P^2=2-2\cos(6\pi/7)-\cos (2\pi/7)-\cos (4\pi/7)+ \cos(4\pi/7)+\cos(6\pi/7)-(1/2)-(1/2)\cos(4\pi/7)+(1/2)\cos(2\pi/7)+(1/2)\cos(6\pi/7)$

$16P^2=(3/2)-(1/2)\cos (6\pi/7)-(1/2)\cos(2\pi/7)-(1/2)\cos (4\pi/7)$

**Identity 3: $ 0 = 1+ 2\cos(2\pi/7)+2\cos(4\pi/7)+2\cos(6\pi/7)$**

$64P^2=6-2\cos(6\pi/7)-2\cos(2\pi/7)-2\cos(4\pi/7)$

$64P^2=7$